# Space between two line in Ck editor Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

[image: Actual Image While Inserting Data In Ck editor]

[image: Image After Inserting And While Retrieve Data Show]

[image: So many Gap between two line]

I want to use Ck editor, but I can't get the actual output to be the same as the inserted data. 
I can't get the space between the two lines.
I want to remove gap between the two line.

Comment: Grammer improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use line height in CK editor 
please check here 
http://ckeditor.com/addon/lineheight